# What is the meaning of "far from inevitable"?

Tags: idioms, vocabulary, idiom-meaning

I know that "inevitable" means that something will definitely happen, but does "far from inevitable" mean it's more or less likely to happen?

Comment: The complication here is that 'inevitable' means 'certain to happen / unavoidable' so negating it (or as here, partly negating it) leads to an ambiguity: 'It's not certain to happen' and/or 'You can prevent this from happening'. Though these overlap, they're not identical. 'Far from inevitable', I'd say, is usually used to mean 'There are certainly ways that can be tried to prevent it from happening'. However, I'd say that the sense is that it's still more likely to happen than not (the ways may not be tried, and they may not work anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If something is **inevitable**, it is, as you know, *absolutely going to happen*.  To be **far from inevitable** means that not only is it *not* inevitable, it's not even close to being inevitable (i.e., *far less likely to happen*).  **Far from inevitable** means it's *not* a sure thing, but still likely (unless action is taken).

Consider these articles:

> [Don’t bank on Hillary: Why a second President Clinton is far from inevitable](http://www.cityam.com/214004/don-t-bank-hillary-why-second-president-clinton-far-inevitable)

and

> [A hard Brexit is far from inevitable](https://www.ft.com/content/f3c86306-840e-11e6-8897-2359a58ac7a5)

In the first, the author is saying that Hilary Clinton is not a sure winner (which, as we sadly saw, was accurate.)  In the second, the author is arguing that a fast and complete exit from the EU is *not* the only option.

Hope that helps.

Comment: OP asks whether the probability that 'it' happens is over or under 50%.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth -- I'm not sure how something can be *more* likely than being inevitable, but I'm sure Douglass Adams could figure it out.  8^)  I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: 'More likely to happen _than not_, or less ...'. The question makes no sense if this is not intended.

Comment: In some cases, the phrase is even used to mean "That's never going to happen."  Only context will tell you how far 'far from' represents.  In an episode of The Simpson's, an icy manager says "We donate a percentage of our profits to charity."  Asked how much, she says, "Zero. Zero's a percent."  For them, donations were far from inevitable.